# Getting compile error "Inferred type does not conform to upper bounds" in java 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, types, functional-programming

I'm working on a small program where I'm trying to learn a more functional programming style with Java 8.

Here's the problematic code

```
private Function<String, IOMessage<List<Polygon>>> parseSuccessfulShapesInput = (input) -> {
    try {
        List<Polygon> shapes =
                Arrays.stream(input.split(";"))
                        .map(shape -> Arrays.stream(shape.split(","))
                                .map(pointString -> Arrays.asList(pointString.trim().split(" ")))
                                .map(coordList -> {
                                    if (coordList.size() != 2) {
                                        throw new RuntimeException("Points given must contain exactly two coordinates");
                                    } else {
                                        return new Point(Double.valueOf(coordList.get(0)), Double.valueOf(coordList.get(1)));
                                    }
                                }).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                        .map(Polygon::new)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new IOMessage.Success<>(shapes);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Exception fail = new Exception("Failed to parse shapes input.", e);
        return new IOMessage.Error<>(fail);
    }
};

private Function<IOMessage<String>, IOMessage<List<Polygon>>> parseShapesInput = (input) -> 
    input.match((IOMessage.Success<String> s) -> parseSuccessfulShapesInput.apply(s.payload),
            (IOMessage.Error e) -> new IOMessage.Error<>(e.t),
            (IOMessage.Quit q) -> new IOMessage.Quit<>()
    );
```

My IDE (Intellij) doesn't show any errors, but when I compile this, I get the following error:

```
Error:(107, 20) java: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
    inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
      inferred: PolyPath.IOMessage<? extends java.lang.Object>
      upper bound(s): PolyPath.IOMessage<java.util.List<PolyPath.Polygon>>,java.lang.Object
```

And If I try to add explicit types to `parseShapesInput` like so:

```
private Function<IOMessage<String>, IOMessage<List<Polygon>>> parseShapesInput = (input) -> {
    return input.match((IOMessage.Success<String> s) -> parseSuccessfulShapesInput.apply(s.payload),
            (IOMessage.Error e) -> new IOMessage.Error<IOMessage<List<Polygon>>>(e.t),
            (IOMessage.Quit q) -> new IOMessage.Quit<IOMessage<List<Polygon>>>()
    );
};
```

Intellij gives me the following error:

```
Incompatible types: IOMessage<capture of ? extends Object> is not convertible to IOMessage<List<Polygon>>
```

And my IOMessage code:

```
public abstract class IOMessage<T> {

    private IOMessage() {
    }

    public abstract <M> M match(Function<Success<T>, M> s,
                                Function<Error, M> e,
                                Function<Quit, M> q);


    public static final class Success<S> extends IOMessage<S> {
        public final S payload;



        public <M> M match(Function<Success<S>, M> s,
                           Function<Error, M> e,
                           Function<Quit, M> q) {
            return s.apply(this);
        }

        public Success(S payload) {
            this.payload = payload;
        }

    }

    public static final class Error<S> extends IOMessage<S> {
        public final Throwable t;

        public <M> M match(Function<Success<S>, M> s,
                           Function<Error, M> e,
                           Function<Quit, M> q) {
            return e.apply(this);
        }

        public Error(Throwable t) {
            this.t = t;
        }
    }

    public static final class Quit<S> extends IOMessage<S> {
        public <M> M match(Function<Success<S>, M> s,
                           Function<Error, M> e,
                           Function<Quit, M> q) {
            return q.apply(this);
        }

        public Quit() {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEA-141715 may be related.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Unlikely. I pasted the code into Eclipse and get the same compile errors.

Comment: How does that conclude that IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have the linked issue when the compiler error is not detected in the editor?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I think the main question here is how the compile-error can be get rid off ;-)

Comment: ***Inferred.*** Not 'inverred'. Read the message.

Comment: Thank you, it is probably related, but I probably should have been more clear in my question. I'm not so much trying to figure out why intellij doesn't report the error as I am trying to fix the error in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain why the compiler doesn't like your code but you can change the method to this

```
    private Function<IOMessage<String>, IOMessage<List<Polygon>>> parseShapesInput = (
            input) -> {
        if (input instanceof IOMessage.Success) {
            return parseSuccessfulShapesInput
                    .apply(((IOMessage.Success<String>) input).payload);
        }
        if (input instanceof IOMessage.Error) {
            return new IOMessage.Error<>(((IOMessage.Error<String>) input).t);
        }
        return new IOMessage.Quit<>();
    };
```

I tried out different things and if you removed the instantiation of `Error` and `Quit` and replaced it by calls of `parseSuccessfulShapesInput#apply` the compiler became happy. I think that the best explanation is that the compiler gets confused sometimes (happens at other occasions as well).

BTW: To get rid off compiler warnings (not sure if they show up in IntelliJ, I use Eclipse), I changed IOMessage like this:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public abstract class IOMessage<T> {

    private IOMessage() {
    }

    public abstract <M> M match(Function<Success<T>, M> s,
            Function<Error<T>, M> e, Function<Quit<T>, M> q);

    public static final class Success<S> extends IOMessage<S> {
        public final S payload;

        public <M> M match(Function<Success<S>, M> s, Function<Error<S>, M> e,
                Function<Quit<S>, M> q) {
            return s.apply(this);
        }

        public Success(S payload) {
            this.payload = payload;
        }

    }

    public static final class Error<S> extends IOMessage<S> {
        public final Throwable t;

        public <M> M match(Function<Success<S>, M> s, Function<Error<S>, M> e,
                Function<Quit<S>, M> q) {
            return e.apply(this);
        }

        public Error(Throwable t) {
            this.t = t;
        }
    }

    public static final class Quit<S> extends IOMessage<S> {
        public <M> M match(Function<Success<S>, M> s, Function<Error<S>, M> e,
                Function<Quit<S>, M> q) {
            return q.apply(this);
        }

        public Quit() {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I didn't need to use your version of `parseShapesInput`. Adding your changes to `IOMessage` along with explicit types for the `Error` and `Quit` return values instead of using the diamond operator seems to have done the trick.

Comment: @Makaque Hm, in my case the changes to `IOMessage` had no effect on the compiler error. I had to change the method as described. But I'm not using the most current Java 8 compiler, so maybe it became "smarter" after that.